# Why does tabularx give a trailing column - and how can I get rid of that?

Tags: tables, tabularx, two-column, width, ieeeconf

So, I am trying to create a table using;

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
\hline
item 11 & item 12 & item 13 \\ \hline
item 21  & item 22  & item 23 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

My only requirement is that if the table is **too wide for the page**, it should automatically adjust all the contents INSIDE of itself so that **it can fit the page** .  ( e.g if there's too much text, introduce line breaks in text and so on .. )

However, the tabularx environment is behaving rather strangely and giving the following result :

[image: why is there an extra 'trailing' column in there ?!]

I just want to know what is the reason for that 'trailing' column appearing & how can I get rid of it? According to the code, I only specified 3 columns, so why the fourth column ?

Also, what can I do to make sure this table **fits on the page**, when I insert all the text and it is too wide ?

I am using **IEEE Double Column Conference Template** on LaTeX

Comment: never use tabularx without an `X` column, you are just using `c`  so it has no way to achieve the specified width (this will also fix your "also..." question as the point of `tabularx` is to adjust line breaking in X columns, but `c` columns do not allow lie breaking so thetable just gets wider as you add more text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, can i ask what is an x column and should i use it in my case ? I would also appreciate if you can take a look at the next part of the question ( fitting the column into the page width ). Thank you ! Edit : i think you answered it in your edit

Comment: any documentation that told you about `tabularx` will have examples of `X` in use, that is the sole extension that `tabularx` has over `tabular`. see `texdoc tabularx`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle many thanks ! and much obliged, i know you're one of the creators of LaTeX :) If you type your guidance as an answer, i will be happy to mark it as the correct solution !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use tabularx without an `X` column, you are just using `c` so it has no way to achieve the specified width (this will also fix your "also..." question as the point of `tabularx` is to adjust line breaking in `X` columns, but `c` columns do not allow line breaking so the table just gets wider as you add more text.